# Code Design Feedback Wanted: Checking if characters in file are of allowed characters

Tags: java

I am designing this method that is used to check the format of a file. Inside a file there will be a grid used to represent a circuit board:

```
X O 1 O O O
X X X O O O
O O O O X O
O 2 O O X O
O X O O O O
```

The only allowed characters are 0,1,2,X,T. I'm trying to design my code to check if each character is one of these allowed values, and if not then I'll throw an exception. The problem is I feel like what I'm currently doing is inefficient. Here is my current code used within my format-checking method:

```
// Check if token is equal to any of the allowed chracters: 0,1,2,T,X
    for (int i = 0; i < ALLOWED_CHARS.length(); i++) {
        if (token.charAt(0) != ALLOWED_CHARS.charAt(i)) {
                lineScanner.close();
                fileScanner.close();
                throw new InvalidFileFormatException("Token at [" + actualRowSize + "][" + actualColSize
                                    + "] is not an allowed character.");
        }
}
```

The `ALLOWED_CHARS` variable is a String object which holds all the allowed characters. I loop through this String for each character in the grid to check it against a current character in the `ALLOWED_CHARS` String. It just seems horribly inefficient, and hoping someone can provide some design feedback on how I can possibly make this better. After I was learning about algorithm analysis and Big-O notation the other week, I'm horribly afraid of using loops now. haha.

Thank you.

Comment: Since your code works, but you just want to make it better, you might want to try asking on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), which is more appropriate for these sort of questions. It's very easy to sign up, and you'll probably get better responses there.

Comment: A simple RegEx can do the job, such as `^[0-2XT]+$` however, I don't know about the complexity.

Comment: @user when suggesting users post on CR it would be great if there was also a suggestion like "_Please read the relevant help center pages like '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and  '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Set` to store all the allowed characters.

```
final Set<Character> allowedChars = Set.of('0','1','2','X','T');
```

To check if a char is allowed in `O(1)` time:

```
if(!allowedChars.contains(token.charAt(0)){
   //....
```

Comment: oh, quite interesting. I've never used the Set data type. Only ever used Arrays, Strings, and Lists. I'll have to check that one out. O(1) is just what I'm looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @kvnr No problem.

Comment: I can't yet. StackOverflow won't let me. I will when it let's me. Do you know how Set works under the hood? Seems like it would have to iterate or something, but I can't see how being O(1)

Comment: @kvnr See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html). Also read [this](https://javaconceptoftheday.com/how-hashset-works-internally-in-java/).

Comment: Wait...now that I'm seeing the index, I'm assuming you're intending this to be put inside my for loop? So how is that different than what I currently have?

Comment: @kvnr Your code would require two layers of loops to check each character in a string.

Comment: How so? In the code I wrote, I only see one loop. If you're talking about the call to `ALLOWED_CHARS.charAt(i)`, then that is only O(1).

Comment: @kvnr You're only checking the first character of token. I've edited my answer to suit that need.

Comment: The entire algorithm with this solution will still run at O(n), as you have to iterate over the input string. Incidentally, OP's original bit of code is also O(n).

Comment: @Taschi It was only `O(n)` because it was only checking the first character of `token`.

Comment: @hev1 ok that makes more sense. If, under-the-hood, it's the contains() method isn't running some loop iteration then it's O(1) and much better. Even if it is O(n), It looks a lot cleaner than the original.

Comment: @hev1, yes, I understand what you mean. I am merely clarifying.

My point is - the fact that kvnr uses two loops and you only use one doesn't make a difference, because your call to Set#contains() has O(1), and so has kvnr's inner loop.

Comment: @Taschi No, my code does the same thing as the code in the question in O(1) time: it checks if the first character of token is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a regex:

```
if(untokenizedInputStream.matches("^[012XT]*$"))
```

^ and $ are the start and end of the input respectively, [012XT] is your class of acceptable characters and the * means there can be an arbitrary amount of them.

Also, your original method is fine. If you have X fields and Y acceptable characters, your inner loop will be executed X * Y times at the worst, meaning its complexity is O(X), which is pretty dang good. Especially with Y = 5 in your case, there is no need to worry.